# Does Oracle have a mistake in their documentation regarding switch case formatting?

Tags: java, formatting

Here is a [reference](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/codeconventions-statements.html) to how switch statements should be formatted (I've never seen this used at the two companies I've worked at):

[image]

And a [contradictory one](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html), which I am partial to (and is IntelliJ IDEA default):

[image]

The obvious discrepancy is in the tabbing of the case statement - whether it's

```java
switch(case) {
case x:
}
```

or

```java
switch(case) {
  case x:
}
```

Is there a right or wrong one?

Comment: This post isn't really suited for Code Review (because you're not asking us to review code). It would be better off on Stackoverflow, but would probably get closed there too as it is **opinion based**. Indeed, Oracle did not make a Mistake here, it's just a different **code style**.

Comment: correct me if im wrong, but if their documentation says, quite literally, that a particular command should "have the following form", doesn't that mean they are making a statement of fact as to java syntax? I'm just trying to ascertain that because the first example doesn't look right to me

Comment: The document you are reading is not a syntax guide, it is about **code conventions** or **code style**. Both examples are syntactically correct and either might be correct style depending on which conventions you adhere to. And by the way, the document you linked is **wildly** outdated: "The last revision to this document was made on April 20, 1999"

Comment: Of course, SunSoft is right and everyone even mentioning the possibility of deviating a heretic. (Where do you suggest to place loop labels?)